# TLC555 Timer very Low or No Output

Tags: timer, 555

[image]

I am trying to simulate TLC555. Simulation results don't show any issue except that the out is almost negligible.

Answer (score 4):

In SPICE, "10M" means "ten milli-ohms".  To get ten **mega**ohms you need to say "10MEG".

So you have connected a 10m\$\Omega\$ resistor between the output and ground, which means that the low output is expected.

Change the value of R3 to 10000K or 10 MEG.

SPICE hails from the 1970s, an era when accommodating both upper and lower case characters was considered a bit of a luxury for serious computations.

Comment: Which simulator does OP use? Some know the difference between the ‘m’ (milli) and ‘M’ (mega) suffix.

Comment: @hacktastical obviously one that doesn’t , with ~200mA flowing into a “10M” resistor. Looks like the Orcad interface, so likely PSPICE.

Comment: Wow, that’s pretty lame on Cadence’s part that they don’t get that right.

Comment: @hacktastical  well, it's backward-compatible so it doesn't break MH inductors or whatever. Always with the trade-offs y'know.

Comment: I get that, nonetheless the schematic to Pspice conversion should deal with that properly. Small ‘m’ has the same meaning for inductance too. Super lame.

Comment: @hacktastical Do any of the 'professional' SPICE programs actually do that? AFAIK, Pspice, HSPICE/Tina, Multisim SPICE, Xspice, LTspice all behave the same and M = m = 0.001. Just a hobbyist-friendly thing?

Comment: It’s not about Spice itself, but about the front end tool to capture the design and translate it to a deck (though I think internally Spice should deal with this too.) Regardless, SI prefix convention is clear about the ‘m’ vs. ‘M’ distinction. The fact that a tool ignores it (as seems evident here) is a bug, not a feature.

Comment: Quick check: LTSpice forcibly translates 'M' to 'm' (milli). You have to explicitly enter 'meg' to get 10e6. You can also enter '10e6'. As good as LTSpice is, I think this is broken. As for the other sims, here we have a user who got tripped up by it in Pspice. So, also broken.

On the other hand Falstad gets it right, SI-unit wise: 'M' is correctly interpreted as 'mega' (10e6.)